# Can't set view origin to negative

Tags: objective-c, uikit, ios8

I have a simple `KeyboardAdjuster` class that is a property of my form views. If one of the form fields is hidden by the keyboard, then entering that field will have an animation to move the whole frame's `origin.y` up, so that the field appears above the keyboard. A very common approach. It also has a few complexities like calculating how much to scroll by when navigating between fields, but that's not important right now. . . I've been using this utility class since iOS5.

**Example Form:**

[image]

**The problem:**

On iOS8 it has simply stopped working.

- When animating the frame starts by snapping in the opposite direction exactly the amount that its supposed to scroll by. And then scrolling back to the origin.
- I tried commenting the animation part out, and simply setting the frame. No effect.

For example if the frame is supposed to be: `{0, -127, 320, 480}` then it will simply stay at `{0, 0, 320, 480}`

Why doesn't this work on iOS8? Has something changed that I've missed?

**About the views:**

- My views are hand-coded, they're a sub-class of a simple form base-view. (Contains keyboard adjuster and a scroll-view). The other elements are added with initial frames of CGRectZero and then laid out manually in `layoutSubviews`

**How the view/controller created:**

There is a RootViewController that acts as a container controller (UIView containment). It:

- Has a main navigation controller
- Has a container to present / dismiss a hamburger menu for the nav controller's top views (these can change).
- Has a container to present overlays with a custom bounce animation.

So the view is created as follows:

```
- (instancetype)initWithView:(INFAcceptGiftView *)view offerDao:(id <INFOfferDao>)offerDao
    locationTracker:(INFLocationTracker *)locationTracker
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.view = view;
        _offerDao = offerDao;
        _locationTracker = locationTracker;
    }
    return self;
}
```

**What triggers the keyboard animation?:**

The UIView is a sub-class of form base view, which is a UITextFieldDelegate:

```
interface INFFormBaseView : UIView <UITextFieldDelegate, INFInputAccessoryDelegate>
{
    UIResponder *_currentResponder;
    INFInputValidator *_validator;
}
```

**When a field is entered:**

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [_validator dismissMessages];
    [_keyboardAdjuster scrollToAccommodateField:textField];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [_keyboardAdjuster scrollToAccommodateField:nil];
}
```

Comment: Are you using Auto Layout? **EDIT** You are using AutoLayout. Will add an answer.

Comment: Just simple UIView sub-classes (or form base view actually), where the contents are put into a scroll-view. The contents have initial size of CGRect zero and are laid out in layoutSubviews. Also the scroll-view's content size is done here.

Comment: Hmm... are you using IB at all?

Comment: No, no .xibs or storyboards at all in this project actually. . but there is a RootViewController that contains some other view controllers. Its responsible for a) Holding a main UINavigationController b) Presenting a menu vc when required (dealloc'd after done) . . (presenting overlay controllers . . had non-standard bounce animation, hence not using [someVC presentViewControler]

Comment: Can you show some code please. Like where you create the view you are trying to animate and when you are trying to animate the view.

Comment: Code added. Thanks so much for your persistent help!

Comment: @Fogmeister, turns out it was related to my RootController. I tried wiring up so that the form controller *was* my root VC and works ok. . . I know where to look now.

Comment: Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a different solution for you which works on both iOS 7 & 8 and Auto Layout.

In my example I have two UITextFields which I move and hide depending on their position and the position of the keyboard. In this particular case, I switch the UITextFields between them and hide the inactive one.

In `viewDidLoad` you register for the following notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardShowed:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

After that you grab a hold of the default frames of your views, in this case the two `UITextFields`:

```
    - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
        [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

        /*** FOR AUTOLAYOUT MODIFICATIONS & ADDITIONS @ RUNTIME ***/

        self.mailTextFieldDefaultFrame = self.mailTextField.frame;
        self.passwordTextFieldDefaultFrame = self.passwordTextField.frame;
}
```

And when you receive `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` you'll start moving your views:

```
- (void) keyboardShowed:(NSNotification*)notification {

    //GET KEYBOARD FRAME
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    //CONVERT KEYBOARD FRAME TO MATCH OUR COORDINATE SYSTEM (FOR UPSIDEDOWN ROTATION)
    CGRect convertedFrame = [self.view convertRect:keyboardFrame fromView:self.view.window];

        if ([self.mailTextField isFirstResponder]) {
            [UIView transitionWithView:self.mailTextField
                              duration:.3f
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                            animations:^{
                                self.mailTextField.alpha = 1.0f;
                                self.mailTextField.frame = CGRectMake(self.mailTextField.frame.origin.x,
                                                                      convertedFrame.origin.y -
                                                                      self.mailTextField.frame.size.height - 25,
                                                                      self.mailTextField.frame.size.width,
                                                                      self.mailTextField.frame.size.height);
                                self.passwordTextField.alpha = 0.0f;
                            }
                            completion:nil];
        } else if ([self.passwordTextField isFirstResponder]) {
[UIView transitionWithView:self.passwordTextField
                              duration:.3f
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                            animations:^{
                                self.passwordTextField.alpha = 1.0f;
                                self.mailTextField.frame = self.passwordTextField.frame;
                                self.passwordTextField.frame = CGRectMake(self.passwordTextField.frame.origin.x,
                                                                          convertedFrame.origin.y -
                                                                          self.passwordTextField.frame.size.height - 25,
                                                                          self.passwordTextField.frame.size.width,
                                                                          self.passwordTextField.frame.size.height);
                                self.mailTextField.alpha = 0.0f;
                            }
                            completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished)) ^{
                        }];
    }
```

And when you hide the keyboard:

```
- (void) keyboardHidden:(NSNotification*)notification {

        //RESTORE ORIGINAL STATE OF TEXTFIELDS
        [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                          duration:.3f
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                        animations:^{
                            self.mailTextField.frame = self.mailTextFieldDefaultFrame;
                            self.passwordTextField.frame = self.passwordTextFieldDefaultFrame;
                            self.mailTextField.alpha = 1.0f;
                            self.passwordTextField.alpha = 1.0f;
                        }
                        completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with this approach. And there's also this great library: https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding . . it turns out the problem was something to do with my RootViewController - it seems UIView containment works differently, or I've set it up incorrectly.

Comment: I'm glad you've figured it out :)! Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution, posting in case it helps someone.

I mentioned above that I'm using UIView containment, so I have a root view controller that:

- Contains a UINavigationController (the root view is replaceable).
- Contains a Menu Controller (dealloc'd when not in use)
- Presents an overlay with custom animation

My root view had layout subviews as follows:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [_mainContentViewContainer setFrame:self.bounds];
}
```

This behaved the way that I wanted it to pre iOS8, but not afterwards. Technically it appears that iOS8 is doing the right thing - I should only be laying out the `_mainConentViewContainer` on startup or orientation change.